# regular expression matching for PO BOX

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches po box or gpo box addresses, basically the rule for the string is:

Basically I want the rule to be:

the first character must be G or P,

If the first character is G, then the following characters must be any combination of characters followed by PO BOX

else if the first character is P, then the follow characters must be O BOX

examples:
    PO BOX,
    GPO BOX.
    G23123PO BOX,
are all ok,

but: 
GO BOX,
G2323O BOX,
are not ok\n

so i tried

^(([g|p](.)*o(.*)box)).*$

but in this case GO BOX is also a match, because the second p is only optionaly, but i can't make it required or it will break the condition when the first letter is also a p!

Please help!

Comment: Rules are not clear and `PO BOX` is in both good and bad list.

Comment: The following fiddle satisfies all the examples given, but doesn't follow your contradictory rules: http://refiddle.com/gxq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples don't match your description.

What about this? It seems that the `g.+` at the beginning is optional, but it's the same from the P on.

```
^(g.+)?(p.+o.+box)$
```

The syntax assumes at least the "extended" regex syntax, like `sed -r` or `egrep` or `Perl`.

You also seem to use uppercase in the examples but lowercase in the regexes. The tricky little regex engines are case sensitive, so you might want

```
^(G.+)?(P.+O.+BOX)$
```

or even

```
/^(g.+)?(p.+o.+box)$/i
```

(at least in Perl).